# Aggregate by day vs aggregate by month database performance

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a performance issue with a table containing historical data aggregated by date.

Trying to store data aggregated by date results in hundreds of thousands of large records.
I assume this creates a performance issue. It takes seconds to minutes to query data.

Trying to store data aggregated by month would result in fewer results even larger.
I observed that results of about 30 Mb will sometimes result in a timeout exception.

Assuming I have no preference, as developer on how the data is stored. What would be a best experience of storing large amount of data?

Comment: I don't get where aggregating by month creates larger records. Assuming you store as an integer, the number 4 and the number 4,000,000 both take up the same amount of space.

Comment: *"Trying to store data aggregated by month would result in fewer results even larger"* What? fewer results are larger? That doesn't make sense if the dataset has the same definition.

Comment: You probably need better indexing. Without seeing your tables, existing indexes, and code, we cannot help

Comment: _I assume this creates ..._ No, don't assume. Measure.

Answer (score 0):

Always store data in the data type appropriate for the domain of values.   If you need a date but never the time then store as a `DATE` but if you need to get precision to the microsecond then you need `DATETIME2`.   Likewise for integers, what is the maximum value you need - choose `TINYINT, SMALLINT, INT, BIGINT` accordingly.

For string values, avoid `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` and use appropriate number of bytes for the size.

Then identify the appropriate normalisation of your tables. Get to 3rd Normal Form and then you can denormalise where appropriate for performance.

30MB is nothing for a database - not sure why you think that is a large amount of data. However, as mentioned indexing, statistics and queries that only select the columns they need will also help.